# How to get the first alphabetic word of string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to retrieve the first alphabetic word of a string, which might include tags as well.

I have tried using split(" ") but it gives me the spaces.

```
let letter = ' <section class="contact" id="contact">';
let firstWord = letter.split (" ");
```

It should just show section as the first word. Is there any way I can do. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the first word, match a non-letter, then one or more letters inside a capturing group, then another non-letter:

```js
let letter = ' <section class="contact" id="contact">';
let [, firstWord] = letter.match(/[^a-z]([a-z]+)[^a-z]/i);
console.log(firstWord);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple regex to match alphabetic (not alphanumeric) words `/[a-zA-Z]+/g`

```js
let letter = ' <section class="contact" id="contact">';
let words  = letter.match (/[a-zA-Z]+/g);  // Match all alphabet 
let firstWord = words.length > 0 ? words[0] : '';
console.log(firstWord);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use several solutions based on what you really need.

For the current scenario, you may match a chunk of 1+ ASCII letters

```js
let letter = ' <section class="contact" id="contact">';
let first_word = (letter.match(/[a-z]+/i) || [""])[0];
console.log(first_word)
```

You may tell the regex engine to only match it if there are no digits or underscores around it using `\b`, word boundaries:

```
/\b[a-z]+\b/i
```

And in case you want to match any Unicode letter word and target **ECMAScript 2018** and newer, you may use

```js
let regex = /\p{Alphabetic}+/u;
console.log("Один,два".match(regex)[0]); // => Один
```

Or, with Unicode word boundaries,

```js
let regex = /(?<![\p{Alphabetic}\p{N}_])\p{Alphabetic}+(?![\p{Alphabetic}\p{N}_])/u;
// Or,
// let regex = /(?<!\p{L}\p{M}*|[\p{N}_])\p{Alphabetic}+(?![\p{L}\p{N}_])/u
console.log("1Один2,два-три".match(regex)[0]); // => два
```

That is, to match 1+ alphabetic chars not preceded nor followed with letters or digits.